# How to hide a view from a stack view in table view cellForRow delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I'd like to know what's the cleanest way to remove a view from a stack view if a certain property in my data model is `nil`. I have a table view which is populated by prototype cells. They look like this:

[image]

The second label text contains an optional value which may be `nil`; I want to hide the label if it's nil. Should I call `removeArrangedSubview` inside the `cellForRow` table view cell method or inside the `CustomTableViewCell` class with a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to hide the label if [optional value] is `nil`

You should set label's `hidden` property to `true` rather than removing it from arranged subview list of stack layout in order to avoid adding it back when the cell gets reused for a different row.

It is mostly a matter of preference where you do it. If most of your cell setup code is in the `cellForRow` function, you should hide and unhide the label from that function as well:

```
if let labelText = model.getTextForMyLabel(indexPath.row) {
    cell.label.text = labelText
    cell.label.hidden = false
} else {
    cell.label.hidden = true
}
```

If you have a setter for label text in the code for your `CustomTableViewCell`, you can use the same approach to set the label's `hidden` property along with its `text`.

Comment: Thanks! Very quick question: do labels have a setter for their `text` property called every time I update their text?

Comment: @Cesare There is a good chance that the setter for label's `text` property checks if the current label text matches the new text that you are trying to set, and skips the actual setting if the new text is the same as the current text.